# generating video from web generate graphics

Tags: javascript, browser, rendering, video-processing

my question may be trivial but I was unable to find an answer so far.

I transitioned from [Processing](https://processing.org) based visualizations to js frameworks, working both front-end and with node.
Great for real-time graphics, but still: If I need to generate a video, what other options I have other than screen record?

This is a particular problem if I need something at a resolution bigger than the webpage, or very resource-heavy, so where I could expect some slow down in real-time visualization

With processing, and I guess other similar tools, it was ok if a frame was taking seconds to render, they were later saved as images and recombined.
And the same about the resolution, it was possible to render in a virtual canvas.

Is there any way to do the same with js based tools?

EDIT: I don't use p5.js, is not a question about that. Mostly my workflow is about mapbox, d3, three.js and Vue.
Thanks

Comment: Googling "p5.js video recorder" returns a ton of results. Have you tried any of those options?

Comment: Actually I don't use p5.js at all and I would prefer not to, I find it quite weird to be honest as a mixture of the java derived patterns and the async web environment. I was using processing originally, but only the java version.

Comment: If your question isn't about Processing then you should probably drop the [tag:processing] tag.

Comment: good point, done, anyway, other suggestions?